# Retrofit2 Interceptor call 2 API

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor

I'am trying to call an API to get cookie and then call another API to send a request.

The problem is that I have a lot of API and in each of these I need a double call
getCookie and than if isSuccessfull I can call the 2th API

I am reading about Interceptor, but how can I use this ?

Now I need to do this:

```
 ApiUtil.validateAuthCookie(authCookieModel.getCookie()).enqueue(new Callback<ValidateAuthCookieModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ValidateAuthCookieModel> call, Response<ValidateAuthCookieModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().valid)
                ApiUtil.addLike(item.getId(), mCookie).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        }
                    });
            else {
                openLogin();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ValidateAuthCookieModel> call, Throwable t) {
            openLogin();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Create an interface, and pass request code param in it. In callback success check the request code of the api you called, and after that call another api with some other request code :)

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, I know this, and this is what I do now but I have a lot of API and for each of them I need to implement this double check. You can see my code...

I am trying to call the first API (check cookie) on an Interceptor. Is this possible ?

Comment: let me share you the strategy I work with,

Comment: Is it a bearer token that you send with all subsequent api calls?

Comment: no, I need to call API_COOKIE (to know if cookie is valid) first than all others APIs

Answer (score 0):

Like this ? but I don't know if this can be done

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        // original request
        Request request = chain.request();

        // new request
        Request newRequest = ApiUtil.validateAuthCookie("123456789").request();
        // new response
        Response newResponse = chain.proceed(newRequest);

        if (newResponse.code() == 200) {
            return chain.proceed(request);
        } else {
            logout();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps I m sharing with you, this is an efficient way of doing things.
Make sure you implement ResponseHandler in your activity or fragment first.

Implement ResponseHandler:-

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements ResponseHandler {}
```

Call api:-

```
//AppManager is my application class of project.
         new RestCaller(SettingsActivity.this, 
AppManager.getRestClient().pushNotification("auth_token", status), 1);
```

Response:-

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Call call, Response response, int reqCode) {

        Utility.dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
        if (reqCode == 1) {
        //call another api like I mentioned above with other request code
}
}
```

This is ApiInterface class.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("updateNotificationClinic")
    Call<UpdateClinic> pushNotification(@Query("auth_token") String token,
                                        @Query("pushNotification") String push);

}
```

Create this class.

```
 public interface ResponseHandler {

        void onSuccess(Call call, Response response, int reqCode);

        void onFailure(Call call, GenericResponse error, int reqCode);

        void onApiCrash(Call call, Throwable t, int reqCode);
    }
```

Create RestCaller class.

```
public class RestCaller {

private int REQ_CODE = 0;
ResponseHandler handler;

    public RestCaller(ResponseHandler context, Call caller, final int REQUEST_CODE) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (REQUEST_CODE <= 0) {
            NumberFormatException ex = new NumberFormatException();
            throw ex;
        }
        REQ_CODE = REQUEST_CODE;
        handler = context;
        ENQUE(caller);
    }

  private void ENQUE(Call call) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if (response.code() == 200 | response.code() == 201) {
                    handler.onSuccess(call, response, REQ_CODE);
                } else if (response.code() == 403) {
                    Toast.makeText(AppManager.getAppContext(), "Code: 403", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    GenericResponse error = null;
                    Converter<ResponseBody, GenericResponse> errorConverter =
                            AppManager.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(GenericResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
                    try {
                        error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
                    } catch (IOException e) {}
                    if (error != null)
                        handler.onFailure(call, error, REQ_CODE);
                    else
                        handler.onApiCrash(call, new Throwable(response.raw().message()), REQ_CODE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof UnknownHostException)
                    handler.onApiCrash(call, new Throwable("Unable to access server. Please check your connection."), REQ_CODE);
                else
                    handler.onApiCrash(call, t, REQ_CODE);
            }
        });
    }


   }
```

Create RetroClient Class.

```
public class RetroClient {
    private Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static RetroClient object;
private RetroClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.retrofit_base_url)
            .addConverterFactory(StringConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static RetroClient getRetroClient() {
    if (object == null) {
        object = new RetroClient();
    } else if (object != null && !object.getRetrofit().baseUrl().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Config.retrofit_base_url)) {
        object = new RetroClient();
    }
    return object;
}

//this is your class where you set your api's.
    private ApiInterface service;

    public ApiInterface getApiServices() {
        return object.service;
    }

    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return object.retrofit;
    }
}
```

Set these method in your application class.

```
public static ApiInterface getRestClient() {
    return RetroClient.getRetroClient().getApiServices();
}


public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    return RetroClient.getRetroClient().getRetrofit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    AuthCookieModel authCookieModel = (AuthCookieModel) FileManager.readObjectPref(MyApplication.getAppContext(), Constants.GENERAL_PREFERENCES, Constants.PREFERENCES_AUTH_COOKIE, AuthCookieModel.class, null);

    // original request
    Request request = chain.request();

    retrofit2.Response<ValidateAuthCookieModel> newResponse = ApiUtil.validateAuthCookie(authCookieModel.getCookie()).execute();
    if (newResponse.isSuccessful() && newResponse.body().valid) {
        // continue with original request
        return chain.proceed(request);
    } else {
        openLogin();

        // problem is HERE, because I need to stop or cancel the chain
       return new Response.Builder()
            .code(600) //Simply put whatever value you want to designate to aborted request.
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
            .message("token expired")
            .request(chain.request())
            .build();
    }
}
```